# How to format nulls in DecimalFormat

Tags: java, formatting, number-formatting

I'm using DecimalFormat to percents with 2 decimal places:

```
DecimalFormat fmt = new DecimalFormat("0.00%");
System.out.println(fmt.format(1.14));   // 114.00%
System.out.println(fmt.format(0.1201)); // 12.01%
System.out.println(fmt.format(null));   // I would like to show "--"
```

How do I specify the format for nulls? I want two dashes.

Comment: Why not use an if statement for that specific case, considering the format for null is different from the default 0.00% anyway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define a custom formatter, but as the method  `DecimalFormat.format` is final, you can't inherit the class and override the method

```java
DashDecimalFormat fmt = new DashDecimalFormat("0.00%");
System.out.println(fmt.format(1.14));   // 114.00%
System.out.println(fmt.format(0.1201)); // 12.01%
System.out.println(fmt.format(null));   // --
```

```java
class DashDecimalFormat {
    private final DecimalFormat formatter;
    public DashDecimalFormat(String pattern) {
        formatter = new DecimalFormat(pattern);
    }
    public String format(Object obj) {
        return obj == null ? "--" : formatter.format(obj);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, OK. It's too bad DecimalFormat doesn't account for nulls. I'll create a class "FullDecimalFormat" (or something along the lines) as in your solution that will accept a second parameter in the constructor for the null format. Thank you.